# how to disable an input field from a group of input fields in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Created a table in angular containing car names. Each raw contains a reorder button, input field, and an edit button.
Values in the input fields were populated using *ngFor.
Initially all the input fields are disabled. When I click the edit button, then the corresponding input field needs to be enabled. But here all the input fields are enabled.
I have gone through so many questions were asked. But could not find any solution.
It would be helpful if someone can help.
Thanks in advance.
**html**

```
<table mat-table width="1500">
<tr>
 <th>Cars</th>
 <td>
  <ul *ngFor='let car of Car'>
   <li >
      <button mat-icon-button color="Green">
         <mat-icon>reorder</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <input mat-input #a id={{car.id}} value={{car.name}} class="text- width" 
        [disabled]=is_edit>
      <button mat-icon-button color="Green" (click)="isDisable()">
         <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
       </button>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

.ts file

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {
  is_edit: boolean;
  public Car: any[] = [{ id: '1', name: 'Maruti' }, { id: '2', name: 'Volkswagen' }, { id: '3', name: 'Ford' }]; 

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.is_edit = true;
  }

 public isDisable(): void {
    this.is_edit = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, you need to have is_edit for every row. So, that you can update while click button for respective field. And you need pass index value of array in edit button click inside isDisable function, using that index you need to object car object.

Your, .ts should be

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {

  public Car: any[] = [{ id: '1', name: 'Maruti', is_edit: true }, { id: '2', name: 'Volkswagen', is_edit: true }, { id: '3', name: 'Ford', is_edit: true }]; 

  public ngOnInit(): void {
  }

 public isDisable(index: number): void {
    this.Car[index].is_edit = false;
  }
}
```

and your html should be

```
<table mat-table width="1500">
<tr>
 <th>Cars</th>
 <td>
  <ul *ngFor='let car of Car; let index as carIndex'>
   <li >
      <button mat-icon-button color="Green">
         <mat-icon>reorder</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <input mat-input #a id={{car.id}} value={{car.name}} class="text- width" 
        [disabled]=car.is_edit>
      <button mat-icon-button color="Green" (click)="isDisable(carIndex)">
         <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
       </button>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, make sure you update the Car object

`public Car: any[] = [{ id: '1', name: 'Maruti', is_edit: false }, { id: '2', name: 'Volkswagen', is_edit: false }, { id: '3', name: 'Ford', is_edit: false }]; ` like this

Comment: I have tried this code. When loading the page a the input fields are enabled. I need them as disabled initially. Then the edit but needs to enable the corresponding input field.

Comment: make default value as true in is_edit for all car objects like this
`public Car: any[] = [{ id: '1', name: 'Maruti', is_edit: true }, { id: '2', name: 'Volkswagen', is_edit: true }, { id: '3', name: 'Ford', is_edit: true }];`

Comment: It is not working. Shows an error like 'Cannot set property 'is_edit' of undefined
    at ..'

Comment: Thank you @madhan kumar. I got the result by replacing [disabled]=car.is_edit.

Comment: How can I implement the same functionality using values from API instead of Car list. From API only id and name will be there.?

Comment: The same process, only the change is hit API call inside ngOnInit, get car objects and you need to insert is_edit property with default value every car object.

Comment: When I sent back the data to API, I need to again remove this is_edit. Is there any other way which is simpler than the mentioned above?

Comment: Create a new object CarModal `{ carObj: car, is_edit: true
}` and pass only CarModal.carObj. May be this can help. No, other way apart from this two.

Comment: Did not get you. Can you please explain?